# Use Flask to run a python script using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to run a python script using javascript.

I installed Flask.

this is my html code :

```
<input type="button" value="tester" onclick="addImage()" />

<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function callPy(data1, data2){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/test",
        data:{data1: data1, data2:data2},
        success:callbackFunc
    });

function callbackFunc(response) {
    $('#result').html('<li>'+response.x+'</li>');
}
function addImage(){
    callPy(1,2);
}
</script>
```

And this is my python code :

```
  import csv
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import matrix

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,request
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', method='POST')
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST'
    data1 = request.form['data1']
    data2 = request.form['data2']
    return "ok""
    return render_template('watermark.html', message='azerty')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

But I have this error in the console :  `jquery.min.js:5 POST http://testFalsk/test 404 (Not Found)`
What I have to make?

Comment: Is the host you are running the server on reachable as `testFlask`?

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in the code you provided (for example, the double double quotes after "ok"). Are you sure the server is running?

Comment: @Karin, which serveur? Flask?

Comment: Yes, the flask server. If you want to be able to call a route on a server, the server needs to be running. Also generally, the default URL the server runs is` localhost:5000`. I'm not sure where you're getting `testFlask` from.

Comment: @Karin, do you know the command to know this?

Comment: Well the clear implication is that you aren't routing to the page you think you are. Just as a matter of interest, how do you serve the page with the HTML in it?

Comment: @holdenweb, what do you mean by "how do you serve the page with the HTML in it" ?

Comment: I mean how does the HTML file containing the call to `callpy` get loaded as a browser page (since your server doesn't appear to be serving it)

Comment: In the consol I have this error : jquery.min.js:5 POST http://testFlask/test 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What happens when you run the Python you posted?

Comment: @Karin, There is the script in the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the parameter name for the allowed methods is `methods` (not `method`) and it accepts a list with the allowed methods. In this case, it will have only one element.

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
```

With this, the check for `request.method == 'POST'` isn't necessary, once this view will only accept this type of requests.

Next, there are some syntax errors in your code: the colon after the `if` statement and the "ok" return string (three double quotes). Also, you have two returns, which isn't valid. To get dict data (as in the `request.form`) the `get` method is recommended. It will return `None` if the key doesn't exist, in oppose to the current way that will throw an exception. 
The corrected method would be as follows:

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    data1 = request.form.get('data1')
    data2 = request.form.get('data2')

    return render_template('watermark.html', message='azerty')
```

Please let me know if you're still having problems or my answer isn't clear nor accurate.

Hope it helps.
Cheers